# How do you find the value(s) of m for which the system has more than one solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  3m&m+12&m-3&3\\
  3&m-3&1&3m\\
  1&1&3&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

For the above matrix, I would like to know how to solve for the value(s) of m for which the system has more than one solution.

I have turned it into reduced row echelon form, which is

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1&0&0&{-3(41m+46)\over (m-6)(8m+19)}-1\\
  0&1&0&{3(8m^2+3m-14)\over (m-6)(8m+19)}\\
  0&0&1&{9\over 8m+19}
\end{array}
\right] $$

Is there even value(s) of m for which the system has more than one solution?

If there isn't, would I write the answer as "no values of m"?

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Be careful when you divide a number, you could have divided by a zero.
- You should examine what happens when $8m+19=0$ and also what happens when $m=6$.

Edit:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  3m&m+12&m-3&3\\
  3&m-3&1&3m\\
  1&1&3&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

reduces to

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&-2(m-6)&-8m-3&3-6m\\
  0&m-6&-8&3m-6\\
  1&1&3&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

reduces to

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&0&-8m-19&-9\\
  0&m-6&-8&3m-6\\
  1&1&3&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

The only possible values for it to have more than one solution is when either $m=6$ or when $m=-\frac{19}{8}$.

Notice that when $m=-\frac{19}{8}$, it has no solution.

When $m=6$, the system becomes

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0&0&-67&-9\\
  0&0&-8&12\\
  1&1&3&2
\end{array}
\right] $$

and we can see that it has no solution as well.

Comment: When I applied elementary row operations, I divided the rows by these terms:
8m+19, m+2, m and m-6.

When I tested the matrix for all these values, 
it had a unique solution for:
m = -2 and m = 0
, and it had no solutions for:
m = 6 and m = -19/8

Does that mean it really does not have a value of m for which the system has an infinite amount of solutions?

Comment: Yes, no such values exist.

Answer (score 0):

It can only have more than one (actually infinitely many) solutions if the matrix is non - invertible and the equations are non contradicting / inconsistent.

Matrix is non - invertible if its determinant is ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.

When I found the values of m for which the determinant of the square matrix is zero, the values turned out to be m=6 and m=-19/8. However when I subbed these values back into the augmented matrix, the system was not consistent. Does that not mean that there is no values of m where there is infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Yes it is true, contradicting or inconsistent equation in linear algebra means there's no solution. Thus there are no $m$s such that our equation has multiple solutions.

Comment: This is imprecise in general. Let $A$ be the system matrix and $A'$ be the augmented matrix. The system is inconsistent $\;\iff\;\operatorname{rank}(A)<\operatorname{rank}(A')$. $\det(A)=0, A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ is just a consequence and not a definition.

Comment: Better word usage: linearly (in)dependent. A system can be (in)consistent.